# Order numerical array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting

I try to order a numeric array, but I don't get it.
What is wrong?

An example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FheDOnr6ZmTJN0bFpgbB?p=preview

```
<select data-ng-model="current" data-ng-options="number as number for number in numbers | orderBy:'number'"></select>
```

Comment: check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/odLERXhXzTHyiGrFi8Xo?p=preview i have make this  `orderBy:'number'` to this `orderBy:number`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function to order too:

```
<select 
 data-ng-model="current" 
 data-ng-options="number as number for number in numbers | orderBy:'valueOf()'">
</select>
```

Should work.

#### Why does it fail?

Cause you were saying to order by the property `number` which doesn't work cause they're just plain integers which doesn't have any property called `number` but they do have a `valueOf` method which does the trick.

You could also use just `number` without quotations (as suggested in a comment) so it will just pass the variable instead of a property.

Comment: Its quite interesting thing you've shared Antonio. Will you please elaborate this line for me `You could also use just number without quotations (as suggested in a comment) so it will just pass the variable instead of a property.` ?

Comment: Sure @Vineet. When you use a string: `orderBy:'number'` angular tries to find the property `number` inside the value. In this case, they're integers so they can't have that property by default. However if you only pass `number` to orderBy with no quotes, you're passing the variable, that is, the raw integer so orderBy can work out the order.